# foreach through div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got some trouble about doing an loop through the following construct:

```
<div id="items">
    <p id="test1">
        <select  name="1" id="1"><option>A</option><option selected>B</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="to" id="to">
        <input type="text" name="away" id="awy">
    </p>
    <p id="test2">
        <select  name="2" id="2"><option>A</option><option selected>B</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="to" id="to">
        <input type="text" name="away" id="awy">
    </p>
    <p id="test3">
        <select  name="3" id="3"><option>A</option><option selected>B</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="to" id="to">
        <input type="text" name="away" id="awy">
    </p>
</div>
```

I need to run through test1, test2 and test3 and read the selected option and the values of the text-fields (select, to,away). Doing this if i got only one thing in for example test1 is no problem with query:

```
$('#items').children('p').each(function () {...}
```

But if i add the two text-fields and want to do this for each test (1-3) I have no idea...

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: IDs must be unique.

Comment: Show us the code inside the function!

Comment: ids must be unique... and valid NCName I think : http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName (must start with a letter or an underscore)

Comment: Use a `class` to identify a group of similar elements. Don't overuse `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Ids should represent unique items within a DOM. Use classes instead, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="to" class="to">
<input type="text" name="away" class="awy">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('#items').find('select option:selected, input:text').each(function(){
      alert($(this).val()); //Value of each selected option and text field within the div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need to do the `.children` part.

Try this:

```
$('#items > p').each(function () {
    // you can then use $(this) to reference the currently iterated p element.
    // such as $(this).find('input[type="text"]:first');
    // or
    // $(this).find('input[type="text"]:last');
});
```

Comment: Why not? Yours is a different selector, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Note: First of all give the unique id for all elements.

The following code might help you.

```
$(‘p’).each(function(index){
this.children().get(0).val();

//now do for second and third also
}
```

Comment: `‘’` are no valid string delimiters